# MVVM // ViewModel event being fired on Activity rotation (recreated)

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, components, lifecycle

Reading the [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing_data_between_fragments) I found (sort of) an example of using a `selectedItem` in order to propagate an event being fired to other observers, this is my current implementation:

**ViewModel**

```
public void onListItemClicked(Item item) {
    if (selectedItem.getValue() == item) {
        return;
    }
    selectedItem.postValue(item);
}


public LiveData<Item> getSelectedItem() {
    if (selectedItem == null) {
        selectedItem = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    return selectedItem;

}
```

**View**

```
ListViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel.class);

viewModel.getSelectedItem().observe(this, new Observer<Item>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Item item) {
        if (item != null) {
            openDetailActivity(item);
        }
    }
});
```

And when the user **clicks the list:**

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(Item item) {
    viewModel.onListItemClicked(item);
}
```

All **good and all it works**, the problem is when the **user rotates the screen** and the `ListActivity` is re-created detects a change and will open the `DetailActivity` when subscribing.

I found a workaround which is adding `selectedItem.postValue(null);` on the `getSelectedItem()` but it's a little hacky.

Ofc one could argue that the opening the details activity and propagating the even should be separate, but I was wondering if someone has a better implementation/suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Using the `SingleLiveEvent` is the way to go. This makes sure your `ViewModel` only fires the event once.

Here's the reference article:

- [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)
- Java class can be found in the article

I've created a gist with the `Kotlin` class.
I've been using with success for these use-cases:

- #### [Always up-to-date gist SingleLiveEvent.kt](https://gist.github.com/JoaquimLey/17c9a6d6aaef404b8ffce6596a11c621)

I'll keep the gist up-to-date, but I'll leave the code here also 
(FYI this might be outdated as I won't be editing this answer every time I make a change to the gist):

```
package YOUR_PACKAGE


import androidx.annotation.MainThread
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

/**
 * A lifecycle-aware observable that sends only new updates after subscription, used for events like
 * navigation and Snackbar messages.
 * <p>
 * This avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change (like rotation) an update
 * can be emitted if the observer is active. This LiveData only calls the observable if there's an
 * explicit call to setValue() or call().
 * <p>
 * Note that only one observer is going to be notified of changes.
 */
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val mPending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, Observer<T> { t ->
            if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(@Nullable t: T?) {
        mPending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    /**
     * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
     */
    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }
}
```

---

Old answer:

<strike>So after researching quite a bit and getting with contact with a Google dev. the recommended solution is to have separate responsibilities.
Opening an activity should the response to the click event and not the actual change, this type of `selectedItem` scenarios is especially useful for **decoupled communication** to other listening Views.
**e.g** another fragment in the same activity</strike>